# Wordpress child theme stylesheet doesn't seem to work

Tags: css, wordpress

I've created a child theme for the one I want to make changes on, but changes I make in style.css don't show up on the site.

Here's what's in my style.css

```
/*
 Theme Name:     Soundstage Child Theme
 Description:    Soundstage Child Theme
 Author:         xxxxx
 Template:       soundstage
 Version:        1.0.0
*/

/* =Imports styles from the parent theme
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
@import url('../soundstage/style.css');


/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.logotext {
    font-family: "Life Savers", cursive; 
    font-weight:400; 
    position:relative; 
    top:12px;
    right:90px;
    }

.menu-item {
    font: 18px/20px cutive,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
    }
```

Just to check, I installed a plugin to add extra CSS — and this CSS works fine in there.

EDIT: By the way, templates in the child theme directory work fine.

EDIT2: I just noticed WP is calling the stylesheet with a parameter after it (the current WP version), but I'm not quite sure where it's coming from or why the stylesheet is different if I look at it with the ver= on and off.:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='soundstage-css' href='http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/soundstage-child/style.css?ver=3.6.1' type='text/css' media='all'/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is coming from the way WordPress enqueues (and then prints) scripts. By default it will print the WordPress version as the version in the query string *(good on you for being up to date)*. It does this in an effort to prevent cacheing when there are file changes.

Generally, the output of your css should not change, regardless of query string. When this occurs often the first place to look is your `.htaccess` file (found in the root of the directory where you have installed WordPress). [WordPress' default `.htaccess` rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29) should be fine, but if you may have other rules, they may be to blame.

Although, it is not a permanent fix, adding the following `.htaccess` directive (at the top of the file), will allow you to troubleshoot the problem:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/soundstage-child/style\.css$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

If the error stops, then another directive in your `.htaccess` file is causing the strange behavior of `style.css` vs. `style.css?v=3.6.1`.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. It was what WP-supercache put into .htaccess. Since I decided not to use the plugin, I just removed it all.

Answer (score 0):

Not all wordpress themes support child theme.
You could use the Custom Css function included in [Jetpack](http://jepack.me) or you could use a custom css [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=custom+css) from the wordpress plugin directory.