# Wordpress Child Theme Changes Taking Forever

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I set up a child theme and got it to work fine. However, now whenever I make any changes they aren't reflected on the website for hours. They update eventually but not until a very long time has passed.

And, I should also say I have no cache plug-in and I've cleared my browser cache.

When I switch from the child to the parent theme, the old css and javascript disappears. And, when I activate the child theme again the old css and javascript reappears but none of the new changes.

Here's my code for the child function.php file:

```
<?php
//* Code goes here

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'zero'; // This is 'zero-style' for the Zero theme.

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

function zero_child_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script('zero child script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/zero_child_script.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zero_child_script');
```

Here's my code for the child style.css file:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Zero Child
 Theme URI:    
 Description:  A Child them of The Zero Creative theme for WordPress OpalTeam is a fully responsive theme that     looks great on any device. That's the best for any kind of crowdfunding     online sites. Follow us on Themeforest to     receive newest updates</a>
 Author:       The Opal Wordpress Team
 Author URI:   http://
 Template:     zero
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         black, green, white, light, dark, two-columns, three- columns, left-sidebar, right-sidebar, fixed-layout, responsive-layout,  custom-background, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured- images, flexible-header, full-width-template, microformats, post-formats,  rtl-language-support, sticky-post, theme-options, translation-ready,  accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  zero-child
*/

/*Glossary

1. Header Styles
2. Slider Styles

*/

/*=====1. Header Styles=====*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 1230px) {

  .logo-wrapper {
    width: 35% !important;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
        -o-transition: all .5s ease;
        transition: all .5s ease;
      }

    }

/*=====2. Slider Styles=====*/

h1#type-text {
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

And the javascript file in the child theme:

```
//Add background to logo on scroll

function ScrollBg(){
  var bg = document.getElementsByClassName('logo-wrapper')[0];
  var ypos = window.pageYOffset;
  var screenWidth = '1229';

  if (window.screen.width > screenWidth) {
    if (ypos > 589) {
      bg.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
    }
    else{
      bg.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", ScrollBg);
```

The url is http://c2pm.misterekwebdesign.com

I also tried changing the .htaccess rewrite rules based of this post
 ([Wordpress child theme stylesheet doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198562/wordpress-child-theme-stylesheet-doesnt-seem-to-work))
to see if that fixed it but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try with admin editor?. Are you using FTP for file upload?

Comment: @vel I actually tried with both and neither made a difference. When I look it up in chrome dev tools I can see the old settings.

Comment: Did you check the file permission?